# $\int^{\pi}_0 \log{\sin{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus

I saw a integral like this and try to solve it by using
$$
\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}\sin{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\cdots\sin{\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}}\ = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}
$$

The $\log$ is based on $e$.

The following is what I try:
$$
\int^{\pi}_0 \log{(\sin{x})}dx=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}(\frac{\pi}{n})\log{(\sin{\frac{i\pi}{n}})}\\=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\frac{\pi}{n}\log{(\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}\sin{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\cdots\sin{\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}})}\\=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\frac{\pi}{n}\log{(\frac{n}{2^{n-1}})}=\pi\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\frac{\log{(\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}})}{n}\\=-\pi\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}{\frac{2^{n-1}}{n}\frac{2^{n-1}-n2^{n-1}\log2}{2^{2n-2}}}=-\pi\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}{\frac{1-n2^{-1}\log2}{n}}\\=\frac{\log2}{2}\pi
$$

But I'm not sure whether I did right for the whole evaluation.

Please help me to check, appreciate.

BTW, my typesetting is by tablet, perhaps it's not neat.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(\frac{n}{2^{n-1}})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(\frac{n}{2^{n-1}})^{\frac{1}{n}}=\log\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the notation you have used, although I can say that the final answer should be twice that and negative. Edit : (I assume you mean base-10 log by log)

Comment: By log, do you mean log base 10 or the natural log?

Comment: @Philosophiae I try to make it clear. It's natural logarithm.

Comment: @allegro.sostenuto Natural log.

Comment: @monotoneoperator So the answer should be $\log{(\frac{1}{2})}\pi$ ?

Comment: @xfireskyx yes the answer should be $\pi\log\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @xfireskyx your proof has a little mistake in $$\dots=\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(\frac{n}{2^{n-1}})=-\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n-1}}{n}\frac{2^{n-1}-n2^{n-1}\log2}{2^{2n-2}}=\dots$$ I don't know  how to get this equality.

Comment: @monotoneoperator that's because the denominator tends to infinty, then in my mind, $\log(\frac{n}{2^{n-1}})$ tends to -$\infty$, so I put a negative outside in order to get $\lim\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and use L'Hopital rule.

Comment: I think your idea is very beautiful, your answer connect the relation between the product $\sin\frac{\pi}{n}\dots\sin\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$ and the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}\log(\sin x)dx$ which make my eyes lit up!

Comment: @xfireskyx L'Hospital rule? you say $\lim_{x\to\infty}\pi\frac{1}{x}\log(\frac{x}{2^{x-1}})$?

Comment: @monotoneoperator Yeah, but I see I don't need to do it.

Comment: @xfireskyx yes, after an easy checking, L'Hospital rule is right! so your mistake appears at $$\dots=-\pi\frac{1-n2^{-1}\log2}{n}$$, may be you lost $2^{n-1}$ when multiply.

Comment: @monotoneoperator Got it ! Thanks very much !

Comment: You are wellcome, best wishes!

Comment: Doesn't using L'Hopital's Rule for this limit just result in an endless loop?

Comment: I'm still not at all sure how you got from the the first step to the second step in the limit, did you try using L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: I've seen quite a few methods to evaluate this particular integral, and this is a particularly interesting approach. Well done to both you and @Philosophiæ who helped complete the proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the method provided in the other answer is certainly the best way to solve this problem, if you are keen on understanding how to solve it via the limit approach you gave, the following would work:

$$\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}\right)}{n}$$

From here, we can move the n in the dominator to the exponent of the argument of the logarithm like this:

$$\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\left(\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}\right)^{1/n}\right)$$

In this case, since the natural logarithm is a continuous function we can swap the order of the limit and the function, yielding:

$$\pi\ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}\right)^{1/n}\right)$$

Which simplifies to:

$$\pi\ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}{2^{1-\frac{1}{n}}}\right)$$

The limit as $n$ approaches infinity of the denominator is clearly 2 as the exponent simplifies to $1-\frac{1}{\infty}$

The limit of the $n^{th}$ root of $n$ is 1, which can be shown using the following reasoning:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}$$
By L'Hopital's Rule:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1}=0$$

Therefore:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}=e^{0}=1$$

Resulting in $\pi\ln(\frac{1}{2})$ or $-\pi\ln2$

Comment: Nice solution (+1)!

Answer (score 6):

The notation you have used is a bit confusing and your final answer is also wrong. But, this is a very standard question and there is a very neat way to solve this integral, which is as follows
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\ln (\sin(x))dx &= \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx+\int\limits_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\ln(\sin(x))dx\\
&= \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(x))dx+\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos(x))dx\\
&=
\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)\right)dx\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left(\sin(2x)\right)dx-
\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(2)dx\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\ln(\sin(x))dx-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$

and hence

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\ln (\sin(x))dx =-\pi\ln 2$$

Comment: I know that it's right, but I need to think twice what I ignored for the limit, thanks for your help and answer.